# issues with deploying hugo site to google cloud app engine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, hugo

So I'm trying to deploy my Hugo blog to google cloud app engine, but I'm having issue with the URL mapping,I have played with it a lot but nothing seem to work

The home page is working and I can see the the posts but when I click on a post I got error: Not Found message

app.yaml

```
env: standard
runtime: nodejs16
service: default
handlers:
  - url: /
    static_files: public/index.html
    upload: public/index.html
  - url: /posts
    static_dir: public/posts
  - url: /(.*)
    static_files: public/\1
    upload: public/(.*)
```

Files structure

[image]

website link: https://www.waelfadlallah.com/

---

Thank to [NoCommandLine](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15211203/nocommandline) the issue is resolved, here is how my app.yaml looks like now

```
env: standard
runtime: nodejs16
service: default
handlers:
  - url: /posts/(.+)/
    static_files: public/posts/\1/index.html
    upload: public/posts/(.+)/index.html
  - url: /assets
    static_dir: public/assets
  - url: /
    static_files: public/index.html
    upload: public/index.html
```

Comment: Your post has a url - ```https://www.waelfadlallah.com/posts/my-first-post/```. Your app.yaml says any url with a path starting in ```/posts``` is a static file and the corresponding file is somewhere in ```public/posts``` folder. Does that mean you have a file named ```my-first-post``` within the ```posts``` folder?

Comment: No my-first-post is a folder and inside it is an index.html

Comment: What I'm trying to achieve is to map anything that starts with posts to /posts/*name of the post*/index.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See if this works....

Instead of using `static_dir`, try using `static_files` and have your handler like the example [here](https://github.com/mattgartner/appengine-static-sites/blob/master/app.yaml). That example has (the sample below). See if you can modify it to suit your pattern

```
- url: /([^\.]+)([^/])
  static_files: www/\1\2/index.html
  upload: www/(.+)
```

Comment: I did a little tweak i used the first rule from the sample that NoCommandLine provide, I will add my full app.yaml in the original question so it help other people